# Multiple Divs inside Container of Multiple Divs inside a Div

Tags: html, css, css-float

Ok, I have Multiple Divs inside of a container, 3 to be exact, the two on the outsides have variable information that adjust the height of the container they are in.  The div in the middle has multiple divs inside it that also have variable information that I want to also be able to adjust the height of the overall container as well and also have variable width so if someone expands their window, the content will expand with it.  I can't seem to keep the middle div in the middle when content is placed in it that requires it to move to the next line, it pushes the 2 outside divs down.  I need all three of the Divs to be able to adjust the height of the container to keep the background color going to the bottom of the longest div.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fLe5f65/13/) is the basic code of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="morecontent">
            More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: For SEO purposes, I would really like to have the middle div (the main content) listed first in the HTML and I prefer not to rearrange the order of the elements within the
HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the HTML as shown, you can try the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="morecontent">More Content...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">Left...</div>
    <div class="right">Right...</div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color:#09F;
    padding: 0 60px 0 60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    border:dotted;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -100%;
    right: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.right {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    border:solid;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.content {
}
.morecontent {
}
```

The trick involves adding left/right padding to the containing block and then using 
negative margins to get the floats to sit in the padded areas.

This trick is sometimes referred to as the "Holy Grail" and is explained in more detail
at: http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wrudgcaL/

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did think about that and that may be what I have to go to, but for SEO purposes, I would really like to have the middle div (the main content) listed first in the HTML

Comment: Let me take a 2nd look, there are several ways of doing this.

Comment: Marc, that worked beautifully!  Thanks for the link as well, that was very informative reading!

Answer (score 0):

This is an option: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/2fLe5f65/17/

**HTML** Same code as you posted above

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="morecontent">
            More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content More Content 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color:#09F;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.main {
    border:solid;
    margin-left:53px;/*width of left div + its border width*/
    margin-right:53px;/*width of right div + its border width*/
}
.left {
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    border:solid;
}
.right {
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    border:solid;
}
.content {
}
.morecontent {
}
```

Comment: This will work as long as the `.main` container is the tallest block.  Since the `.left` and `.right` blocks are absolutely positioned, their height will no longer control that of the parent container.

Comment: This can be fixed with JS though

Comment: Thank you ctwheels, that looks like that will work.  I would rather have a CSS only fix, but using JS is not a problem either.  I plan on eventually making the 2 outside divs (left and right) follow the screen when there is more content in the middle and you have to scroll.  Any idea if this JS code would interfere with me being able to do that?

Comment: @Fletcher I'm not quite sure what you mean by "follow the screen" could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained that a little better...using the following script so that when you scroll and the menu (left and right) get to a certain point it becomes absolute on the screen     $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".left").css("top",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});

Comment: @Fletcher like `position:sticky;`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yep, exactly like that...guess I need to hit the books more, lots apparently that has changed that I need to learn

Comment: @Fletcher the only issue with `position:sticky;` is its browser support at the moment. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky